# Why would applying a cssClass to a s:label create two labels in Struts 2?

Tags: html, struts2, code-generation

Any thoughts on why this...

```
<s:label label="%{getText('userDetails')}" cssClass="headerLabel"/>
```

results in this..

```
<label class="label" for="">User Details:</label>
<label id="" class="headerLabel"></label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is just what the `<s:label>` tag  does.  There is no way I can find to apply css to the first part though.

Comment: Struts tags are buggy... I would suggest you to use HTML tags and Disply tags instead of struts tag..

Comment: I agree in this case, `<s:label>` is not one of Struts' better tags.  The HTML tag `label` is better used.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of struts are you using (2.2.1)?

Did you try to change your label directive to:

```
<s:label label="%{getText('userDetails')}" cssClass="headerLabel" theme="simple"/>
```

If it still doesn't work create a new file called label.ftl inside your WEB-INF/classes/template/simple/ application folder with this content:

```
<label<#rt/>
<#if parameters.id??>
 id="${parameters.id?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#if parameters.cssClass??>
 class="${parameters.cssClass?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#if parameters.cssStyle??>
 style="${parameters.cssStyle?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#if parameters.title??>
 title="${parameters.title?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#if parameters.for??>
 for="${parameters.for?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/simple/common-attributes.ftl" />
<#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/simple/dynamic-attributes.ftl" />
><#rt/>
<#if parameters.nameValue??>
<@s.property value="parameters.nameValue"/><#t/>
</#if>
</label>
```